# Which is it - Tassle or Tassel?

Tags: british-english

I found "tassle" used in a few British books. Is it a British spelling of "tassel" or an error on the authors part?.

Comment: FYI when I searched, I could not even find tassle. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/223404/a-word-for-decorative-cords-on-uniforms?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to hanging ornaments? If so, "tassel" is correct. "Tassle" is an incorrect spelling